# Drupal 7 - Install.php doesn't have "Demonstration site" option. How to restore?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to migrate and restore a Drupal 7 website onto a new server. The previous dev only zipped and gave me the site files+DB. I've gotten to the step where I've added the site files to the new server, there was no install.php in the files from the previous dev, so I've added the file. Went to website.com/install.php, got the "Standard" and "Minimal" options, but there's no "Demonstration Site" option. How do I restore in this situation? Am I missing something?

Imported old database into server and tried again. Got this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'database_user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/vhosts/website.page/httpdocs/includes/lock.inc)
```

**Extra Details on above Database issue.**

I managed to make the website display on new server. It's currently hosted on Plesk. Previously, I had the database Access Control set to **Allow local connections only**, but once I set the access control to **Allow remote connections from any host**, it started to display the site. I am a bit worried why though as the website files and database are both hosted on same server. Shouldn't **local connections only** work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use old DB backup to restore site , you need to edit settings.php to put database connexion information, so after that you'll access to your old drupal data

Comment: Hi @Fky thanks for the reply. I'm getting this error when connecting the old database:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'database_user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/vhosts/website.page/httpdocs/includes/lock.inc). Any insights?

Comment: In settings.php, did you change 'database_user' to the user name that has the right privileges on the database, and did you change the database name?

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk I created the same database_user and same database_name on the new server. The just import the old database into the new server.

Comment: If you go to website.com/install.php and there is no database connection, this is the behaviour of Drupal. So I would double check settings.php and database privileges

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk added extra details on top. Managed to display the website, but I'm a bit worried of the database access control settings.

Comment: So, 1 step further now. I'm not used to Plesk so perhaps someone else can clarify that. Or ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you go to website.com/install.php and there is no database connection, this is the normal behaviour of Drupal. So I would double check settings.php and database privileges.